# How do I show a list of data in android studio based on the presence of a particular value in firebase-realtime-database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to retrieve a list of users who chose a specific value.

Here is my database that is created in Firebase. I'm trying to print a list of users and their addresses who selected the option "Food" in "providedServices" node.

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1rqZ.png)

I'm iterating through the database and trying to use an IF statement to find users that chose that option however, I am stuck. Below is a snippet of my code:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz9Zu.png)

Can someone please help me? Btw, I'm a beginner, so please go easy on me :')

The following is the FoodActivity page where

```
public class FoodActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseDonors;

    ListView listViewDonors;

    List<Donors> donorsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);

        listViewDonors = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDonors);

        donorsList = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public FoodActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference donorsRef = rootRef.child("donors");
        Query provideServicesQuery = donorsRef.orderByChild("provideServices").equalTo("Food");
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Donors donors = ds.getValue(Donors.class);
                    donorsList.add(donors);
                    Log.d("TAG", donors.getDonorName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
            }
        };
        provideServicesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        
    }
}
```

The following is the Donors class that is used.

```
public class Donors {
    String donorID;
    String donorName;
    String providedServices;
    String donorBusinessName;
    String donorAddress;
    String donorEmail;
    String donorPhone;


    public Donors(String donorID, String donorName, String providedServices, String donorBusinessName, String donorAddress, String donorEmail, String donorPhone) {
        this.donorID = donorID;
        this.donorName = donorName;
        this.providedServices = providedServices;
        this.donorBusinessName = donorBusinessName;
        this.donorAddress = donorAddress;
        this.donorEmail = donorEmail;
        this.donorPhone = donorPhone;
    }

    public Donors() {
    }

    public String getDonorID() {

        return donorID;
    }

    public String getDonorName() {

        return donorName;
    }

    public String getProvidedServices() {

        return providedServices;
    }

    public String getDonorBusinessName() {

        return donorBusinessName;
    }

    public String getDonorAddress() {

        return donorAddress;
    }

    public String getDonorEmail() {

        return donorEmail;
    }

    public String getDonorPhone() {

        return donorPhone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only the objects that have the `provideServices` property set to "Food", you should  definitely use a query as in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference donorsRef = rootRef.child("donors");
Query provideServicesQuery = donorsRef.orderByChild("provideServices").equalTo("Food");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Donors donors = ds.getValue(Donors.class);
            donorsList.add(donors);
            Log.d("TAG", donors.getDonorName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
provideServicesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Besides that fact that the `donorsList` will be populated with `Donors` objects, you'll also see in the logcat the name of all donors who have the `provideServices` property set to "Food".

Comment: Hey Alex, I tried your way but the app page shows up blank even though in the database, there are already some donors that have chosen "Food" as the providedServices :(

Comment: And that case, please edit your question and add the exact code that you are using now, add a more detailed screenshot of your database and **tell me if the name of the donors are printed out are the logcat**.

Comment: I've edited the question. Does it help? If you need more details, please do let me know :) Also, No, I don't think the donors are printed in the logcat yet.

Comment: First of all, make all the properties in your `Donors` class `private`. To see if something is printed out in the logcat, try to search in Android Studio by `"TAG"`. If it still doesn't work. please **add a more detailed screenshot of your database**, as also requested earlier.